# Changing the eclipse jdk

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I have java jdk 1.6 update 1 installed on my pc as well as jdk 1.8.0_11, my eclipse uses the 1.6 version, how do i change it to 1.8 and on doing so, will I need to change any further setting for android application development?

Answer (score 2):

In your Eclipse IDE go to `Window->Prefernces->Java->Complier`
and set Compiler compliance level to required version
[image: See the screen shot]

**UPDATE:** You need a newer version of Eclipse. At least 3.7SR1.

Answer (score 1):

In your project in Eclipse you can select "Project -> Properties" and then go to "Java Compiler", then uncheck the checkbox "Use compliance from execution environment 'JavaSE-1.6' on the 'Java build path'".
Then select the complier compliance level.

Comment: If you are referring to the compiler compliance level (atm it is 1.6) it is giving me options from 1.3-1.7

Comment: What release of Eclipse are you using? Kepler?

Comment: my eclipse version is 4.2

Comment: OK - version 4.2 is Juno and there is no Java 1.8 support in that release. I suggest you down the [latest Eclipse release](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-java-developers/keplersr1) for Java, and it can either be Kepler/Luna/ or Mars versions. This should work for you.

Comment: Hello - did any of our responses help you at all? If so - then you should click the "UP" arrow on one of them to indicate the answer is correct, which can also help other users when they search on stackoverflow for the same problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Right click on project - Build Project - Libraries- Add  Library - Select the desired Java Version (Alternate one)

[image]

Comment: devmehta - you can also use this suggestion to add your JVM Environment; Just click on 'Add Library' as in this post, then 'JRE System Library', then select 'Alternate JRE' and add a new one.